# Errors doesn't show on page on ajax submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make table insert new row with ajax, php, mysql. So far I was able to make the table and on correct data in the fields to submit and save data to database.

Now I'm trying to make some validations and display errors if any but I don't see errors on the page.. I see them only under developer console.

This is my insert row on the table

```
<tr id="new_row">
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
    <td><input type="email" id="new_email"></td>
    <td>
         <input type="button" id="insert" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row()">
    </td>
</tr>
```

**ajax** part

```
function insert_row()
{
    var name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("new_email").value;
    $.ajax
    ({
          type:'post',
          url:'insert.php',
          data:{
               insert_row:'insert_row',
               name_val:name,
               email_val:email
          },
          success:function(response) {
               if(response!="")
               {
                   var id=response;
                   var table=document.getElementById("user_table");
                   var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
                   var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+id+"'><td id='name:"+id+"'>"+name+"</td><td id='email:"+id+"'>"+email+"</td>";

                   document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
                   document.getElementById("new_email").value="";
               }
          }

    });
}
```

And **PHP** part `insert.php`

```
if (isset($_POST['insert_row'])) {

     $name=$_POST['name_val'];
     $email=$_POST['email_val'];

     if($name < 4) { echo 'please enter the name';exit(); }
     if($email < 4) { echo 'please enter email';exit(); }

    $value = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM client WHERE name= ?');
    $value->bindParam(1, $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $value->execute();
    $result = $value->fetch();


    $value1 = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM client WHERE email= ?');
    $value1->bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $value1->execute();
    $result1 = $value1->fetch();

    if ($result > 0) 
    {
        echo 'Name already exist';
        exit();
    }
    elseif ($result1 > 0) 
    {
        echo 'Email already exist';
        exit();
    }       
    else
    {
          // query for insert here
```

I see none of the errors on the page. Can you show me how to pass them?

Comment: Do you mean the errors of MySQL or js errors?

Comment: You can open the url of the ajax call you see in the Network tab of your Developer console in a new tab/window. Then you will see any errors that might occur.

Comment: You are getting the response but you are not displaying it. You need to either to use an alert(response) in your success handler or assign the response to an `html` element in order to show it.

Comment: Use try catch exception handler which will show you error.

Comment: @Devilscomrade no... the errors from php part.. `please enter the name, email...` etc. Bojan as I said I see them in developer console. I want to show them to the user. Franco can you show me an example for html element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As example you can add a div here:

```
<td>
      <input type="button" id="insert" value="Insert Row" onclick="insert_row()">
       <div id="error" style="display:none"></div>
</td>
```

in your ajax:

```
    success:function(response) {
                       if(response!="")
                       {
                           var id=response;
                           var table=document.getElementById("user_table");
                           var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
                           var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+id+"'><td id='name:"+id+"'>"+name+"</td><td id='email:"+id+"'>"+email+"</td>";

                           document.getElementById("new_name").value="";
                           document.getElementById("new_email").value="";
                          //just in case the error has been shown before
                           $('#error').hide()
                       }else{

                       $('#error').html(response);
                       $('#error').show()
                  }
```

I Hope this will let you go on.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just last adjustment.. is it possible to refresh also page on success only?

Comment: Yes is possible if you want to: window.location.reload(true). Use The 'true' parameter if you need to pull the document from
the web-server again otherwise use 'false';

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Actually doesn't work.. I don't get anything on the page. Only in console..

Comment: Make also sure that you have added the 'error div' correctly (open and closing tags). Check it please.

Comment: Page is loading normally but if I enter  username which already exist i don't get `echo 'Name already exist'` on the page.

Comment: You sad that you were getting the return values correctly in your console. I didn't check of your 'php' code is working correctly. Also note that if you enter both an incorrect name and email you will get only one of the two response back. You can not get it both in the way you are doing. You need to change your 'php' code and pass the values in an array which you will send back to the response. I hope this will make sense for you.